# determinant formula

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be nxn matrices and let $A(i|j)$ denote the matrix $A$ obtained by removing the ith row and jth column of $A$. I want to show the cofactor of $AB$ is equal to the cofactor of $A$ times the cofactor of $B$. So I try to show that

$$\sum_k \det(A(i|k)B(k|j))= \det(AB)(i|j),$$ but I don't see why this is true. Can anyone explain?

Comment: It's a particular case of the Cauchy-Binet formula, since $\left(AB\right)\left(i\mid j\right)$ is the product of the matrix $A$ without its $i$-th row times the matrix $B$ without its $j$-th column. If you want all details spelt out, see Exercise 5.33 (and its solution) in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 21 March 2018](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2018-03-21).